# saving the value from NumberPicker android

Tags: java, android, numberpicker

I am having an issue with the android NumberPicker. i am sure it is because of the 
onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) call. i don't have an oldVal or newVal currently in the code... my question is how to save the value from NumberPicker without using a TextView xml object. Currently i cannot scroll back to lower numbers on the NumberPicker, i am assuming that it is because the onValueChange method... i don't want to display the current or previous number picked on screen so id like to avoid setting up a TextView in the xml, but I'm not sure how to save the current value of the number picker...

java file:

```
package com.example.android.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static final int MIN_VAL = 0;
static final int MAX_VAL = 255;
NumberPicker red, green, blue;
View v;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    red = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.redPicker);
    green = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.greenPicker);
    blue = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.bluePicker);

    red.setMinValue(MIN_VAL);
    red.setMaxValue(MAX_VAL);
    red.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    green.setMinValue(MIN_VAL);
    green.setMaxValue(MAX_VAL);
    green.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    blue.setMinValue(MIN_VAL);
    blue.setMaxValue(MAX_VAL);
    blue.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    v = findViewById(R.id.color_box);
    v.setBackgroundColor(0x0000FF00);

    red.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF11F000);
        }
    });
}

}
```

xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="187dp">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/redPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/greenPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/bluePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />

</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/color_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "i cannot scroll back to lower numbers"

Comment: i can scroll up on the number picker, but when i try and choose a lower number it freezes for a second and then chooses a higher number.

Comment: what do you do on **onValueChanged()**. can you post that method?

Comment: its posted at the bottom of the java file. But that is my issue, I'm not sure what to do there. what i want to do is save the number from the picker... all i have now is that it change the background color of a view.

Comment: --save the new number

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't my code, it was an issue with the virtual device being sloooooow... i started on a phone and it works as expected.